# Apps Script Gsheets - Paste same value in different cells - efficient solution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Gsheet-workbook with 15 sheets. There is a central place to change the timeframe. Once a user changes it centrally - it should apply the change in all the sheets.

However, within each sheet he also can change the time locally without affecting others.

Hence, I've just wrote a script that pastes the central value to all the other places. However, it's a slow `for loop` and takes something like 15 seconds to complete:

```
function set_time_frame() {

  var Gsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('General information');

  var inputs =  Gsheet.getRange('f3:f4').getValues();

  var n = 15; // sheets to place

    for ( var i = 1; i <= n; ++i ){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[i];

  sheet.getRange('c4:c5').setValues(inputs);

    }
}
```

Is there a way for example to paste immediately to multiple ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Sheets API v4? Please think of this as one of several answers. In order to use following script, please enable Sheets API for Advanced Google Services and API console as follows.

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Google Sheets API v4

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at API console

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "sheets". And click Google Sheets API.
  - Click Enable button.

#### Modified script :

```
function set_time_frame() {
  var Gsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputs =  Gsheet.getSheetByName('General information').getRange('f3:f4').getValues();
  var n = 15; // sheets to place
  var resource = {};
  resource.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
  var data = [];
  for ( var i = 1; i <= n; ++i ) {
    data.push({
      values: inputs,
      range: Gsheet.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() + "!c4:c5"
    });
  }
  resource.data = data;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, Gsheet.getId());
}
```

#### Flow of modified script :

1. Retrieve values that you want to import.
2. Create JSON data as a resource. This data includes all sheets and values that you want to import.
3. Run Sheets API with the created resource.

#### References :

- Advanced Google Services : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- Sheets API v4: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Comment: That was cool. But another question. Once I run the script, I'm getting into trouble with dates. The original inputs are dates. Once they are pasted with the new script it looks like "Wed Oct 25 23:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017" - and this is not recognized as a date. What can I do?

Comment: @Ilja I'm sorry for the inconvenience. About the next question, please modify from ``var inputs = Gsheet.getSheetByName('General information').getRange('f3:f4').getValues();`` to ``var inputs = Gsheet.getSheetByName('General information').getRange('f3:f4').getDisplayValues();``. When this modification didn't work, can you show me your Spreadsheet?

Comment: Eventually I worked around using a cell next door with the formula: =Text(RC1,"dd-mmm-yyyy") -- Then GScript assumes it's text and I'm getting it exactly the way I wanted into the other Sheets. Thank you! The running time is 5 times down.

Comment: @Ilja I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I could study from your question. Thank you.